# How to call a Ressource by dynamic String?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Normaly I would do this:

```
ResourcesLocal.Resources_MainMenu_Index.ResourceManager.GetString(temp);
```

for retrieving a dynamic string from my Ressource.

Sadly now my Ressource Name will be dynamic too, so "ResourcesLocal.Resources_MainMenu_Index" will be saved a string in my settings.

How to do that call now?

```
string resName = "ResourcesLocal.Resources_MainMenu_Index";
string translation = ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your approach is the best idea, but to solve your question: You can use reflection.

```
  var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");
  var resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Fully.Quallified.Namespace.Name.Resources", assembly);
  var wantedString = resourceManager.GetString("theStringYouWant");
```